# Creating JSON arrays in Boost using Property Trees

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm trying to create a JSON array using boost property trees.

The [documentation](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_49_0/doc/html/boost_propertytree/parsers.html#boost_propertytree.parsers.json_parser) says: "JSON arrays are mapped to nodes. Each element is a child node with an empty name."

So I'd like to create a property tree with empty names, then call `write_json(...)` to get the array out. However, the documentation doesn't tell me how to create unnamed child nodes. I tried `ptree.add_child("", value)`, but this yields:

```
Assertion `!p.empty() && "Empty path not allowed for put_child."' failed
```

The documentation doesn't seem to address this point, at least not in any way I can figure out. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 123):

Simple Array:

```
#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

ptree pt;
ptree children;
ptree child1, child2, child3;

child1.put("", 1);
child2.put("", 2);
child3.put("", 3);

children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child1));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child2));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child3));

pt.add_child("MyArray", children);

write_json("test1.json", pt);
```

results in:

```
{
    "MyArray":
    [
        "1",
        "2",
        "3"
    ]
}
```

Array over Objects:

```
ptree pt;
ptree children;
ptree child1, child2, child3;


child1.put("childkeyA", 1);
child1.put("childkeyB", 2);

child2.put("childkeyA", 3);
child2.put("childkeyB", 4);

child3.put("childkeyA", 5);
child3.put("childkeyB", 6);

children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child1));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child2));
children.push_back(std::make_pair("", child3));

pt.put("testkey", "testvalue");
pt.add_child("MyArray", children);

write_json("test2.json", pt);
```

results in:

```
{
    "testkey": "testvalue",
    "MyArray":
    [
        {
            "childkeyA": "1",
            "childkeyB": "2"
        },
        {
            "childkeyA": "3",
            "childkeyB": "4"
        },
        {
            "childkeyA": "5",
            "childkeyB": "6"
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Please note that the numbers are encoded as strings and not numbers.

Comment: Hi @Luke, I am having this issue with the strings. How can I encode them as numbers?

Comment: I couldn't find a good solution when using the boost library. I switched to rapidjson instead.

Comment: There are a bunch of restrictions with this: You cannot create arrays with just a single element, and repeating the same element multiple times doesn't work properly for me either.

Comment: There is an easier way to make pure value arrays that doesn't require an intermediate child object: children.push_back(ptree::value_type("", "1")); the value must be formatted as a string however

Answer (score 22):

What you need to do is this piece of fun. This is from memory, but something like this works for me.

```
boost::property_tree::ptree root;
boost::property_tree::ptree child1;
boost::property_tree::ptree child2;

// .. fill in children here with what you want
// ...

ptree.push_back( std::make_pair("", child1 ) );
ptree.push_back( std::make_pair("", child2 ) );
```

But watch out there's several bugs in the json parsing and writing. Several of which I've submitted bug reports for - with no response :(

EDIT: to address concern about it serializing incorrectly as {"":"","":""}

This only happens when the array is the root element. The boost ptree writer treats all root elements as objects - never arrays or values. This is caused by the following line in boost/propert_tree/detail/json_parser_writer.hpp

```
else if (indent > 0 && pt.count(Str()) == pt.size())
```

Getting rid of the "indent > 0 &&" will allow it to write arrays correctly.

If you don't like how much space is produced you can use the patch I've provided [here](https://svn.boost.org/trac/boost/ticket/3828)

Comment: This isn't right. After dumping to JSON, rather than getting an array, I get this: { "": "", "": "" }.

Comment: Updated the post to reflect why this is happening and how to fix it.

Comment: Sad to report that it seems that it is still impossible to create arrays as root elements in 1.53.0.

Comment: You can also try to call the internal helper direct, and fake the indent.

boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json_helper(stream, root,1,false);

Comment: @Gabor: Any reason why you're passing `pretty=false` there? It works, but the default in `write_json` is to pretty-print.

Comment: this is a 'simple' way to skip the indention code, and get skip the indent code  refereed by the answer. With pretty=false the result is smaller, and it works. Because it's a long time ago, I expect that with current version it work without this workaround.

Answer (score 12):

When starting to use Property Tree to represent a JSON structure I encountered similar problems which I did not resolve. Also note that from the documentation, the property tree does not fully support type information:

> JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. However, all type information is lost; numbers, as well as the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form.

After learning this, I switched to the more complete JSON implementation [JSON Spirit](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/recipes/JSON_Spirit.aspx).  This library uses Boost Spirit for the JSON grammar implementation and fully supports JSON including arrays.

I suggest you use an alternative C++ JSON implementation.

Comment: Lots of new libraries since I wrote this answer. Here is a nice one that I came across recently:
https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: And Boost 1.75.0 introduced Boost JSON

Answer (score 6):

In my case I wanted to add an array to a more or less arbitrary location, so, like Michael's answer, create a child tree and populate it with array elements:

```
using boost::property_tree::ptree;

ptree targetTree;
ptree arrayChild;
ptree arrayElement;

//add array elements as desired, loop, whatever, for example
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
  arrayElement.put_value(i);
  arrayChild.push_back(std::make_pair("",arrayElement))
}
```

When the child has been populated, use the `put_child()` or `add_child()` function to add the entire child tree to the target tree, like this...

```
targetTree.put_child(ptree::path_type("target.path.to.array"),arrayChild)
```

the put_child function takes a path and a tree for an argument and will "graft" arrayChild into targetTree

Answer (score 0):

As of `boost 1.60.0`, problem persists.

Offering a `Python 3` workaround ([Gist](https://gist.github.com/pbertoni/0b1adcda389349d88097c5588d9941d5)), which can be syscalled just after `boost::property_tree::write_json`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3


def lex_leaf(lf: str):
    if lf.isdecimal():
        return int(lf)
    elif lf in ['True', 'true']:
        return True
    elif lf in ['False', 'false']:
        return False
    else:
        try:
            return float(lf)
        except ValueError:
            return lf

def lex_tree(j):
    tj = type(j)
    if tj == dict:
        for k, v in j.items():
            j[k] = lex_tree(v)
    elif tj == list:
        j = [lex_tree(l) for l in j]
    elif tj == str:
        j = lex_leaf(j)
    else:
        j = lex_leaf(j)
    return j


def lex_file(fn: str):
    import json
    with open(fn, "r") as fp:
        ji = json.load(fp)
    jo = lex_tree(ji)
    with open(fn, 'w') as fp:
        json.dump(jo, fp)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    lex_file(sys.argv[1])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want JSON in C++, there's no need for Boost. With this [library](https://github.com/nlohmann/json#json-as-first-class-data-type) you can get JSON as a first class data type that behaves like an STL container.

```
// Create JSON on the fly.
json j2 = {
  {"pi", 3.141},
  {"happy", true},
  {"name", "Niels"},
  {"nothing", nullptr},
  {"answer", {
    {"everything", 42}
  }},
  {"list", {1, 0, 2}},
  {"object", {
    {"currency", "USD"},
    {"value", 42.99}
  }}
};

// Or treat is as an STL container; create an array using push_back
json j;
j.push_back("foo");
j.push_back(1);
j.push_back(true);

// also use emplace_back
j.emplace_back(1.78);

// iterate the array
for (json::iterator it = j.begin(); it != j.end(); ++it) {
  std::cout << *it << '\n';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Confused with the official document and the above answers.
Below is what I understand.

Property Tree consists of nodes.
Each node is like below

```
 struct ptree
    {
       map<key_name,value>          data;
       vector<pair<key_name,ptree>> children; 
    };
```

To put 'value' into data     with 'put'
To put 'node'  into children with 'push_back'\

```
// Write 
    bt::ptree root;
    bt::ptree active;
    bt::ptree requested;
    bt::ptree n1, n2, n3;
        
    n1.put("name", "Mark");
    n1.put("age", 20);
    n1.put("job", "aaa");

    n2.put("name", "Rosie");
    n2.put("age", "19");
    n2.put("job", "bbb");

    n3.put("name", "sunwoo");
    n3.put("age", "10");
    n3.put("job", "ccc");

    active.push_back   ({ "",l1 });
    active.push_back   ({ "",l2 });
    requested.push_back({ "",l3 }); 
    root.push_back     ({"active", active});
    root.push_back     ({"requested", requested});

    bt::write_json("E:\\1.json", root);


    // READ
    bt::ptree root2;
    bt::ptree active2;
    bt::ptree requested2;
    bt::ptree r1, r2, r3;

    bt::read_json("E:\\1.json", root2);

    // loop children
    for (auto& [k,n] : root.get_child("active"))
    {       
        cout << n.get<string>("name", "unknown");
        cout << n.get<int>   ("age" , 11);
        cout << n.get<string>("job" , "man");
        cout << endl << flush;
    }
```