# Boost property write_json incorrect behaviour

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I am coding a JSON wrapper for Boost property tree.
Currently the focus is on writing the resulting JSON into a string or a file.

Using boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, *pt) the resulting property tree is written in a string.

But this method do not understand what is a true, false, null or a number.
Everything is converted to a string.

Reading the Boost documentation this is a limitation of the library.
Is there any way to modify this behavior?

Comment: [Duplicate](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855741/why-boost-property-tree-write-json-saves-everything-as-string-is-it-possible-to), as mentioned in the first answer.... although the first answer would be nice to have at the duplicate location.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855741/why-boost-property-tree-write-json-saves-everything-as-string-is-it-possible-to) In this link is a fix for the problem.

It involves changing boost code, because of that I tried another alternative.
My solution involves regular expressions:

```
std::string JSONObject::toString() const
{
    boost::regex exp("\"(null|true|false|[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)\"");
    std::stringstream ss;
    boost::property_tree::json_parser::write_json(ss, *pt);
    std::string rv = boost::regex_replace(ss.str(), exp, "$1");

    return rv;
}
```

Basically I search for the keywords: true, false, null and any type of number.
The matches are replaced with the same without quotes.

Comment: and you move the limitation so that if i want to have a string with only numbers or true/false/null as string - i can't have it :-) however everything is better than changing boost code i suppose.

Comment: Thanks, that regexp saved me some headache. Though it fails with negative numbers a the moment. I've changed it to work with negative numbers too: `"\"(null|true|false|-?[0-9]+(\\.[0-9]+)?)\""`