# Boost Json Write error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11

Tags: c++, json, boost, boost-propertytree

I am trying to write Json data to a string using Boost library but I am facing a compilation error:

```
error: no matching function for call to ‘boost::property_tree::basic_ptree<std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char> >::push_back(std::pair<const char*, const char*>)
```

My c++ code is

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

#include <boost/property_tree/ptree.hpp>
#include <boost/property_tree/json_parser.hpp>

namespace pt = boost::property_tree;

int main()
{
  std::string enc = "Enoded data";

    pt::ptree root;
    pt::write_json(std::cout, root);

    pt::ptree image_node;
    image_node.push_back(std::make_pair("content", enc));
    root.add_child("image", image_node);

    pt::ptree features_node;
    features_node.push_back(std::make_pair("type", "LABEL_DETECTION"));
    features_node.push_back(std::make_pair("maxResults", 1)); 
    root.add_child("features", features_node);
    pt::write_json(std::cout, root);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`boost::property_tree::ptree::push_back`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id-1_3_32_10_7_1_1_1_3_22-bb) takes a `boost::property_tree::ptree::value_type` as parameter, which is not the same as `std::pair<const char*, const char*>`. So, you'd need eg. :

```
features_node.push_back(pt::ptree::value_type("type", pt::ptree("LABEL_DETECTION")));
```

Or better yet, just use [`boost::property_tree::ptree::put`](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/release/doc/html/boost/property_tree/basic_ptree.html#id-1_3_32_10_7_1_1_1_3_71-bb) :

```
pt::ptree root;

root.put("image.content", enc);
root.put("features.type", "LABEL_DETECTION");
root.put("features.maxResults", 1);

pt::write_json(std::cout, root);
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I have successfully compiled on that direction and written to stringstream successfully. However, the max value shows always string, but I need to get it as integer. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: @nocturnal_abu : that really is a new question. But you're in luck : someone has [already asked it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855741/why-boost-property-tree-write-json-saves-everything-as-string-is-it-possible-to).