# Why boost::property_tree::write_json() convert integer value to string? It is incorrect.

Tags: c++, json, boost

My input: data.txt

```
{
        "target_url":"www.19lou.com/forum-1637-thread-10031471311655793-1-1.html",
        "trespassing_field":{
            "ratetype":5,
            "spider":{
                "prod_name":"name",
                "link_src":1 
            }
        }
}
```

use code:

```
boost::property_tree::ptree json_tree;
boost::property_tree::read_json("data.txt", json_tree);
std::stringstream json_main_pack;
boost::property_tree::write_json(json_main_pack, json_tree);
LOG(NOTICE) << "json: " << json_main_pack.str();
```

output:

```
{
    "target_url": "www.19lou.com\/forum-1637-thread-10031471311655793-1-1.html",
    "trespassing_field": {
        "ratetype": "5",
        "spider": {
            "prod_name": "name",
            "link_src": "1"
        }
    }
}
```

write_json() convert integer value to string.It convert `"ratetype":5` to `"ratetype": "5"`.It is incorrect.
How to convert accurately？Input integer value, then output integer value.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why boost property tree write\_json saves everything as string? Is it possible to change that?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2855741/why-boost-property-tree-write-json-saves-everything-as-string-is-it-possible-to)

Comment: @ dewaffled Thanks. It is a way to solve the problem. But it is not graceful...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the Boost.PropertyTree documentation [here](https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_68_0/doc/html/property_tree/parsers.html#property_tree.parsers.json_parser), it looks like all type information is lost. Relevant quote:

> JSON values are mapped to nodes containing the value. However, **all type information is lost; numbers, as well as the literals "null", "true" and "false" are simply mapped to their string form.**

Emphasis mine. Looks like you might need to use a different JSON parser if you want to retain type information, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! It seems I need to find another way.

Comment: @Griyn Find a JSON library. Boost Property Tree is a property-tree library

Comment: @sehe Hello. I am encountering the same issue. From your response, it appears that using boost json it is not possible to write an int/double  that stores the values as int/double respectively and not force convert it to string?  Your comment is more than 4 years old. In this time has boost come up with a json library? Do you have any recommendations for a JSON library? Boost is able to properly read a json file where an int is stored as an int (without the string quotations) -- but while writing an int, it unfortunately outputs the quotations.

Comment: @Tryer Google is your friend! https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_81_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html (since boost 1.75.0). Regarding Boost Property Tree, the answer contains a link to the actual documentation, where you can see that indeed nothing has changed (obviously, because Property Trees are still not JSON. Or XML for that matter).

Comment: As always, one encounters the answer after posting a question on SO! Yes, for the last few hours I have been trying to update my property tree code to boost json code!

Comment: @Tryer - here's what the OP's code would look like in my universe: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/1161e8bb18dc525c