# Can this boost ptree block be shorter (and smarter)?

Tags: c++, boost, boost-propertytree

I'm creating a JSON string exploiting boost `ptree` library but I'm finding it tedious just by doing the following. I need to add a simple array like `"metric.name" : [A, B]` to the `metrics` ptree. Can I do better than this? Or at least write this in a cleaner way.

```cpp
      pt::ptree metric_avg;
      metric_avg.put("", 9999);
      pt::ptree metric_std;
      metric_std.put("", 0);
      pt::ptree metric_distr;
      metric_distr.push_back({"", metric_avg});
      metric_distr.push_back({"", metric_std});
      metrics.add_child(metric.name, metric_distr);
```

Comment: you'd be better off using a json library, ptree is convenient but if you want a specific JSON output you'll run into limitations

Comment: Do you have any recommendation for that? I heavily use ptree inside this project and the json formatting occurs just 2/3 times so I'd rather prefer sticking with ptree as long as I can do what I need to.

Comment: [nlohman](https://github.com/nlohmann/json/) is quite easy to use and gives some nice syntax

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd write some helper functions

```
template<typename T>
pt::ptree scalar(const T & value)
{
    pt::ptree tree;
    tree.put("", value);
    return tree;
}

template<typename T>
pt::ptree array(std::initialiser_list<T> container)
{
    pt::ptree tree;
    for (auto & v : container)
    { 
        tree.push_back(scalar(v));
    }
    return tree;
}
```

That way you can write

```
metrics.put(metric.name, array({ 9999, 0 }));
```

Comment: Yes this is probably the best shot I got sticking with ptree. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I would:

**[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/c1cbaf740457af31)**

```
ptree metric_avg;
auto& arr = metric_avg.put_child("metric name", {});
arr.push_back({"", ptree("9999")});
arr.push_back({"", ptree("0")});
```

Or **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b833dff4a4b7775b)**

```
for (auto el : {"9999", "0"})
    arr.push_back({"", ptree(el)});
```

Or even **[Live On Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/770e6cbd2e9f022d)**

```
for (auto el : {9999, 0})
    arr.push_back({"", ptree(std::to_string(el))});
```

All of which print

```
{
    "metric name": [
        "9999",
        "0"
    ]
}
```

See also [JSON Array using Boost::Ptree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64016751/json-array-using-boostptree/64037072#64037072)

Comment: I've found @Caleth answer to be more general and flexible and I ended up writing my own template functions but yours goes straight to the point I was looking for originally so thanks anyway.

Comment: Oh yeah, I +1'ed @Caleth's answer before. It's nice!