# How to read Json string starting with square brackets in it?

Tags: c++, json, boost

I am using c++ code to read json string to retrieve value based on specific key names. Example of my json response from web API is in array format like below.

```
 [
    {
    "username": "123456",
    "useraddress": "abc",
    "data": [
                {
                    "schedule": true,
                    "task": "abc",
                    "risk": "1",
                } 
            ],
     "date": "0000-00-00"
    }
]
```

Like the above format is the actual response. I have to retrieve date value using key "date".

My code snippet:

```
{

std::stringstream jsonString;

boost::property_tree::ptree pt;

jsonString << ws2s(Info).c_str();

boost::property_tree::read_json(jsonString, pt);

std::string date = pt.get<std::string>("date");

}
```

'Info' in above snippet is wsstring containing json response data.

I can able to retrieve "date" if [] square brackets are removed manually. Since it is array format, if I pass without removing brackets, read_json throws error.

Can somebody help this out?

Comment: If you are parsing JSON-data at a scale this might be a more robust alternative: https://github.com/simdjson/simdjson

Comment: Property tree isn't a general purpose JSON parser, if you want to parse arbitrary JSON documents use a dedicated JSON parser like https://github.com/nlohmann/json

Comment: E.g. see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2114466/creating-json-arrays-in-boost-using-property-trees

Comment: I think we should stop closing these questions. Instead we should be advertising Boost JSON. The question wasn't tagged property-tree, but is was  tagged JSON (and titled as such_

Comment: @sehe why boost JSON rather than any of the other myriad JSON libraries, seems opinion based and therefore off topic to me

Comment: @AlanBirtles It ws tagged [tag:c++] [tag:boost] [tag:json]. Color me silly

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yeah. Boost Property Tree is a property tree library, not JSON.

You're in luck though, Boost has a JSON library now https://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_75_0/libs/json/doc/html/index.html

> Note: your input isn't valid JSON either, because JSON doesn't strictly allow trailing commas. You can enable them with an option in Boost JSON though:

**[Live On Compiler Explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/T9o8b6)**

```
#include <boost/json.hpp>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    std::string input = R"(
         [
            {
            "username": "123456",
            "useraddress": "abc",
            "data": [
                        {
                            "schedule": true,
                            "task": "abc",
                            "risk": "1",
                        } 
                    ],
             "date": "0000-00-00"
            }
        ])";

    boost::json::parse_options options;
    options.allow_trailing_commas = true;
    auto json = boost::json::parse(input, {}, options);

    for (auto& el : json.as_array()) {
        std::cout << el.at("date") << "\n";
    }
}
```

Prints

```
"0000-00-00"
```

Comment: Note that Boost JSON can also be used without boost: https://github.com/boostorg/json

Comment: Note also, Boost JSON has "databinding" customization points `value_to` and `value_from` which make working with your own datatstructures a lot less painful: https://godbolt.org/z/Yfn4ET